# javascript form validation textfield length

Tags: javascript, validation

i got a problem on validate the student ID, it require 10 numbers, the problem i met is when i key in a valid student ID, it still return false. Please help me to check mycoding, thank you very much.

example of my Student ID = "1101106363"

```
if ((document.appsub.id.value == "") || !(isNaN(document.appsub.id.value)) || (document.appsub.id.value.length < 11))
    {
        alert("Please enter the correct Student ID");
        document.appsub.id.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

update: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/rVswq/1/

Comment: The method you have chosen for accessing an element of the document is not up-to-date and not safe for all browsers. You should use something like `document.getElementById()` instead, or `document.getElementsByTagName()` if you want to work on an array of elements. To make life easier for yourself consider making yourself acquainted with jQuery. It will simplify your life!

Comment: @cars10 tried, can point to me where wrong, thank you [link]jsfiddle.net/rVswq/1/

Comment: Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/rVswq/3/ . You made a mistake with parentheses in the if clause and also `id.innerHTML.length` was wrong --> `id.value.length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `document.getElementById` method to select the element properly.

```
var el = document.getElementById("yourid");
if (!(isNaN(el.value)) || (el.value.length < 11))
    {
        alert("Please enter the correct Student ID");
        el.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: ... and of course without the `!`operation in front of `isNaN` ... ;-)

Comment: Actually you don't but this is better practice for cross browser compatibility

Comment: I know his code was a little weird so i just put the correct way there

Comment: `el.innerHTML.length` does not get you what you want. Take `el.value.length` instead! And. of course, you can leave out the first condition `(el.value == "")` as this will always result in a length<10 ...  ;-) (10 digits were required)

Answer (score 1):

There is something strange here.
You are checking if the value is null, OR if it IS a number (isNaN returns true if the value IS NOT a number, if you place !isNaN the result is true if the value IS a number), OR if the length is inferior to 11.

If you want to be sure that the inserted value is not null, a number and its length inferior to 11 you should write

```
if ((document.appsub.id.value == "") || isNaN(parseInt(document.appsub.id.value)) || (document.appsub.id.value.length > 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you don't need the NOT operator

```
if ((document.appsub.id.value == "") || isNaN(document.appsub.id.value) ||    (document.appsub.id.value.length < 11))
{
    alert("Please enter the correct Student ID");
    document.appsub.id.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IF statement is wrong. You want:

```
if ( (document.appsub.id.value == "") || (isNaN(document.appsub.id.value)) || document.appsub.id.value.length < 11) )
    {
        alert("Please enter the correct Student ID");
        document.appsub.id.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement will catch students ids with length less to or equal to 10.

Test against length like 10 instead